# Z - Values for polygon (shapefile) in R

Tags: r, 3d, visualization

my goal is to create a 3D-Visualization in R. I have a shapefile of urban districts (Ortsteile) in Berlin and want to highlight the value (inhabitants/km²) as a z-value. I have implemented the shapefile into R and coloured the value for desnity ("Einwohnerd") as followed:

```
library(rgdal)
library(sp)

berlin=readOGR(dsn="C...etc.", layer="Ortsteile")

berlin@data

col <- rainbow(length(levels(berlin@data$Name)))
spplot(berlin, "Einwohnerd", col.regions=col, main="Ortsteil Berlins", sub="Datensatz der Stadt Berlin", lwd=.8, col="black")
```

How it is posible to refer a certain polygon (urban district) to a z-value (inhabitant/km²) and how can I highlight this z-value?

Hope that someone will have an answer!
Best regars
SB

Thanks for the answer, but I am still on my wy to find out the best to use the density as z-value so that I can create a 3D Model. I found out that it is not possible to use the polygons of the shape but that it is possible to rasterize the polygon and to use a matrix for a different perspective and rotation.

Here is the code but the final 3D visualization looks not sharp and good enough. Maybe it would be better to calculate the the z-value in anther way so that the first values did not start so high or to use the center of the polygon and than to draw a column in z-direction:

```
library(rgdal)
library(sp)

setwd("C:\\...")
berlin=readOGR(dsn="C:\\...\\Ortsteile", layer="Ortsteile") 

col <- rainbow(length(levels(berlin@data$Name)))  
spplot(berlin, "Einwohnerd", col.regions=col, main="Ortsteil Berlins",                 
sub="Datensatz    der Stadt Berlin", lwd=.8, col="black")

library(raster)

raster <- raster(nrows=100, ncols=200, extent(berlin)) 

test <- rasterize(berlin, raster, field="Einwohnerd")

persp(test, theta = 40, phi = 40, col = "gold", border = NA, shade = 0.5)  

for(i in seq(0,90,10)){     
persp(test, theta = 40, phi = i, col = "gold", border = NA, shade = 0.5)
}

library(rgl)         
library(colorRamps)
mat <- matrix(test[], nrow=test@nrows, byrow=TRUE)
image(mat)
persp3d(z = mat, clab = "m")
persp3d(z = mat, col = rainbow(10),border = "black")
persp3d(z = mat, facets = FALSE, curtain = TRUE)
```

Comment: You are much more likely to get help if you post your shapefile online somewhere (e.g., Dropbox) and provide a link. If your population density data is in a separate file, you should provide that too. Are you trying to create a 3-dimensional map (ala Google Earth), or a choropleth map with polygons shaded based on the value of z?

Comment: Here is a link: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/r35joqzrq5jnhfp/v_jq90etOM The information for the density is in there. In the end I try to create map with polygons shaded based on the value Z :-) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you had in mind?

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(rgdal)           # for readOGR(...) and spTransform(...)
library(RColorBrewer)    # for brewer.pal(...)

setwd("<directory with shapefile>")
map <- readOGR(dsn=".",layer="Ortsteile")
map <- spTransform(map,CRS=CRS("+init=epsg:4839"))
map.data <- data.frame(id=rownames(map@data), map@data)
map.df   <- fortify(map)
map.df   <- merge(map.df,map.data,by="id")
ggplot(map.df, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group))+
  geom_polygon(aes(fill=Einwohnerd))+
  geom_path(colour="grey")+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=rev(brewer.pal(10,"Spectral")))+
  theme(axis.text=element_blank())+
  labs(title="Berlin Ortsteile", x="", y="")+
  coord_fixed()
```

**Explanation**

This is a great question, in that it provides an example of a very basic choropleth map using `ggplot` in R.

Shapefiles can be read into R using `readOGR(...)`, producing `SpatialDataFrame` objects. The latter have basically two sections: a `polygons` section containing the coordinates of the polygon boundaries, and a `data` section containing information from the attributes table in the shapefile. These can be referenced, respectively, as `map@polygons` and `map@data`.

The code above reads the shapefile and transforms the coordinates to [epsg:4839](http://georepository.com/crs_4839/ETRS89-LCC-Germany-N-E.html). Then we prepend the polygon ids (stored in the rownames) to the other information in `map@data`, creating `map.data`. Then we use the `fortify(...)` function in `ggplot` to convert the polygons to a dataframe suitable for plotting (`map.df`). This dataframe has a column `id` which corresponds to the `id` column in `map.data`. Then we merge the attribute information (`map.data`) into `map.df` based on the `id` column.

The ggplot calls create the map layers and render the map, as follows:

```
ggplot:       set the default dataset to map.df; identify x- and y-axis columns
geom_polygon: identify column for fill (color of polygon)
geom_path:    polygon boundaries
theme:        turn off axis text
labs:         title, turn off x- and y-axis labels
coord_fixed:  ensures that the map is not distorted
```

A note on `scale_fill_gradientn(...)`: this function assigns colors to the fill values by interpolating a color palette provided in the `colours=` parameter. Here we use the Spectral palette from [www.colorbrewer.org](http://www.colorbrewer.org). Unfotrunately, this palette has the colors revered (blue - red), so we use rev(...) to reverse the color order (high=red, low=blue). If you prefer the more highly saturated colors common in matlab, use `library(colorRamps)` and replace the call to `scale_fill_gradientn(...)` with:

```
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=matlab.like(10))+
```