# Assigning specific colors to polygons in a shapefile using R

Tags: r, colors, shapefile

I am comparing results of the 2010 and 2014 mid-term elections in the state of Virginia. I am doing this by using a file that has the Virginian congressional districts over the map of Virginia. I want to color the districts that elected a Republican canidate red and color the districts that elected a Democratic canidate blue.
There is more to the project but once I figure out how to do this one thing I will be able to figure out how I will go about the rest of the project.

**I am using the files found here:**

http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=dc20260d27654c64bfa0c2979a317597

**This is the code I am using to plot the shapefile:**

```
library(maptools)
library(shapefiles)

CCBound <- readShapePoly("tl_rd13_51_cd113")
CCBound2 <- CCBound

system.time(plot(CCBound2))
```

This gives me a nice map of Virginia with the ten congressional districts outlined.

How should I go about coloring in the districts as I stated above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `ggplot` solution. You seem to be asking for a base R method, but IMO it's worthwhile to learn ggplot for the added flexibility. This should get you started.

I had to make some assumptions about the format of your data, since you didn't provide it. The code below is just shows how the data is organized in this example

```
# 2010 and 2014 Congressional Election results in Virginia. 
data.2010 <- data.frame(district=sprintf("%02i",1:11),
                   R=c(63.9,53.1,27.2,62.3,50.8,76.3,59.2,37.3,51.2,62.9,48.8),
                   D=c(34.8,42.4,70.0,37.5,47.0,00.0,34.1,61.0,46.4,34.8,49.2))
data.2014 <- data.frame(district=sprintf("%02i",1:11),
                   R=c(63.0,57.9,000.0,60.3,61.0,75.5,60.9,31.7,74.9,56.6,40.4),
                   D=c(34.5,42.1,100.0,37.5,35.8,00.0,36.9,63.0,00.0,40.4,56.9))
data <- cbind(year=rep(c(2010,2014),each=11),rbind(data.2010,data.2014))
data$delta <- with(data,D-R)
head(data)
#   year district    R    D delta
# 1 2010       01 63.9 34.8 -29.1
# 2 2010       02 53.1 42.4 -10.7
# 3 2010       03 27.2 70.0  42.8
# 4 2010       04 62.3 37.5 -24.8
# 5 2010       05 50.8 47.0  -3.8
# 6 2010       06 76.3  0.0 -76.3
```

This plots the maps.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(rgdal)
setwd("c:/users/jlh/desktop/map/virginia.congressional.districts")
map <- readOGR(dsn=".",layer="tl_rd13_51_cd113")
map.data <- data.frame(id=rownames(map@data),district=map@data$CD113FP)
map.data <- merge(map.data,data)
map.df   <- fortify(map)
map.df   <- merge(map.df,map.data)
ggplot(map.df,aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group))+
  geom_polygon(aes(fill=delta),color="grey20")+
  facet_wrap(~year,nr=2)+
  scale_fill_gradient2(low="red",high="blue",mid="white",limits=c(-100,100))+
  coord_map()+labs(x="",y="")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid=element_blank(),
        panel.border=element_blank(),
        axis.text=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks=element_blank())
```

[image]

Note that in 2014 in the 3rd District the Democrat ran unopposed, while the 6th and 9th Districts were contested, but there was no Democrat running.

The posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065480/z-values-for-polygon-shapefile-in-r/21119269#21119269), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791210/r-ggplot2-merge-with-shapefile-and-csv-data-to-fill-polygons/20475268#20475268) have a explanation of the workflow.

Answer (score 1):

The `CCBound` object is a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`. Basically, it is a list of polygons plus a `data.frame` with as many rows as the polygon number which gives some information on each polygon. You can check the `data.frame` through:

```
    CCBound@data
```

From it, we learn that there are 11 districts. From there, you can built a vector of colors with the `red` or `blue` value according to who won the district. The values in the vector must be in the same order as the districts in `CCbound@data`. Once you have built this vector, you can call the `plot` function with the `col` argument. If `cols` is the colors vector, you can just try:

```
    plot(CCBound,col=cols)
```